# Entity Framework SQL query not returning all databases in C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm facing an issue while trying to retrieve a list of databases using Entity Framework in my C# application. The goal is to display the names of all user databases in SQL Server, except for the system databases (master, tempdb, model, msdb). However, despite having the correct SQL query, the resulting list only contains a subset of the databases I expect.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using in the `StartPage_Load` event:

```
private void StartPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var databaseList = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')").ToList();

        foreach (var databaseName in databaseList)
        {
            DataBaseList.Items.Add(databaseName);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `databaseList` only contains a limited number of databases, omitting some that should be included. I've confirmed that the SQL query itself is correct when tested in SQL Server Management Studio, and the user I'm using for both SSMS and the C# application is the same.

I've ensured that the `DatabaseContext` is properly configured, and there are no errors or exceptions being thrown during this process. I've also double-checked the user's permissions on the database server and granted necessary privileges.

Is there something I might be overlooking? Any insights into why the query is not returning the complete list of databases would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that at runtime the connection string is pointing at the same database you are expecting. add `var connectionString = context.Database.GetConnectionString();` and a breakpoint, then verify that matches where you think it is going. When you say the user has the necessary permissions, is you connection string using Trusted_Connection? Also, is this a web application or desktop/console? If a web app, It will be using the app pool user account by default.

Comment: There are a 101 reasons this may not be working. To rule out a whole host of silly problems try assigning your user `sysadmin` role to see if it will resolve your issue. If it resolves it, then it is definitely a permission issue on SQL Server side. (Remember to un-assign the role)

Comment: I suggest temporarily rename a DB and ensure that it flows through in your query, just to be 100% certain it's the correct server. Then I suggest maybe using extended events to capture the query and everything about it https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216771/capturing-queries-run-by-user-on-sql-server-using-extended-events

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to the code and now it works fine.

```
    private void StartPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection($"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = $"SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                List<string> databaseList = new List<string>();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string databaseName = reader["name"].ToString();
                        databaseList.Add(databaseName);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var databaseName in databaseList)
                {
                    DataBaseList.Items.Add(databaseName);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```